# Conditionally set editable or readonly text field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

How to conditionally enable or disable to editable field (edit/read only)? I used session role from database to make condition on the text field. However, I don't know how to proceed it...

```
<?php
include('session.php');
?>

<tr class="row1">
<td width="30%"><div align="left">Customer name1</div></td>
<td width="100%">
    <div align="left">
        <input type="text" name="CMCNA1" id="CMCNA1" style="width:100%;" pattern="[A-Za-z]+" title="Please insert alphabetical only" maxlength="35"/>
    </div>
</td>
```

Comment: You should ask one specific question at a time

Comment: Please give some code what you have tried.and also be specific about the question.I am not getting the things what you actually looking for.

Comment: Thank you very much for correcting me~ I still can't figure out the solution, anyone help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: <?php $readOnly = true; ?> <input type="text" <?php echo $readOnly ? 'readonly' : ''; ?> name="test" />

Comment: Sorry, may be i described not clearly, in simplest world, i want conditionally change the interface... such coding like this, but not after submit...

Comment: @WhSol, if i want to change it readonly without condition, then would like to use <input type="text" name="CMCNA1" id="CMCNA1" readonly="readonly"/>, but i can't figure how to conditionally change it, any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it's an old post, but just in case, for those who have this needs.
Base on the code of [Narayan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36784333/conditionally-set-editable-or-readonly-text-field/36794882#36794882), maybe by doing this (with jquery):

```
<script type="text/javascript" >

function makerCheckerField()
{
    var role= <?php echo $_SESSION['login_user_role']; ?>;

    var maker='Maker';

    if (role === maker){
        $('#CMCNA1').attr('readonly', 'readonly');
    } else {
        $('#CMCNA1').removeAttr('readonly');
    }
} 
</script>
```

If I am not wrong the `readonly` property works like [this](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html-markup-20120329/input.text.html#input.text.attrs.readonly) :

> readonly = "readonly" or "" (empty string) or empty
>       Specifies that element represents a control whose value is not meant to be edited.

Maybe you will have to manage correctly the differents states of roles (what happens if you came back to the default state etc...).

You can also play with

```
.setAttribute, .getAttribute and .removeAttribute
```

I don't know if this is what you was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -->>

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
function makerCheckerField()
{
var role= <?php echo $_SESSION['login_user_role']; ?>;
var maker="Maker";
if (role === maker) //  equal value and equal type
{
    $("#CMCNA2").attr("readonly", true);

} else {$("#CMCNA2").attr("readonly", false);}
}
 </script>
```

Comment: The text field still able to edit although i log in id attribute is "Maker". Any idea? I still can't figure out the solution. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @JacobChong try === in if condition to check  equal value and equal type. I have added in code also.

Answer (score -1):

you can add attribut readonly="true" to make the input readonly/not editable:

```
<input type="text" name="CMCNA1" id="CMCNA1" style="width:100%;" pattern="[A-Za-z]+" title="Please insert alphabetical only" maxlength="35" readonly="true" />
```

Comment: this is not conditionally set the text field~ What i measure on the question is conditionally set the text field to editable or readonly based on customer role